# Как быстро удалить пустые элементы из объекта типа object[,]?

Tags: c#

Есть объект *data* типа *object[,]*.
Пример его наполнения:

```
[1, 1]  "Данные1"   object {string}
[1, 2]  null        object
[1, 3]  null        object
[1, 4]  "Данные2"   object {string}
[1, 5]  null        object
[1, 6]  null        object
[1, 7]  "Данные3"   object {string}
[1, 8]  "Данные4"   object {string}
[1, 9]  null        object
```

Как можно быстро удалить пустые элементы?

Пробовал что-то типа такого:

```
var myarray = data.Cast<object[,]>().ToList().Where(c => c != null).ToArray();
```

Выдаётся ошибка...

В результате я хочу видеть такое наполнение:

```
[1, 1]  "Данные1"   object {string}
[1, 2]  "Данные2"   object {string}
[1, 3]  "Данные3"   object {string}
[1, 4]  "Данные4"   object {string}
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: у вас в вашем 2мерном массиве используется только одно измерение. Добавьте второе, расставьте данные в шахматном порядке и все поломается.

Comment: Исходный массив имеет фиксированное число строк, но в строке может быть разное количество ненулевых элементов. Например, в 1-й будет 5 ненулевых элементов, во 2-й - 3 ненулевых элемента, и ещё 2 значит будут null. То есть нельзя построить итоговый массив совсем без нулей в заданной геометрии. Может быть имеет смысл перейти на зубчатый массив?

Answer (score 1):

Методы `System.Linq` работают с коллекциями (к примеру, `IEnumerable`). Да, существует конвертация с коллекции на массив, но она работает только с одномерными массивами. Поэтому в основном применяют ступенчатые массивы для работы с `System.Linq`. При этом формат данных будет отличаться, к примеру: `object[][]`.

Для работы с двумерным массивом (или более) можно использовать стандартный метод перебора значений.

```
object?[,] data = new object?[,]
{
  { 1, "Данные1" },
  { 2, "Данные2" },
  { 3, null },
  { 4, "Данные4" },
  { null, "Данные5" },
  { null, null },
  { 7, "Данные7" },
  { null, null }
};

int rows = data.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
int columns = data.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
object[,] output = new object[0, columns];
int filteredRowsCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
  bool isNullExists = false;
  for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
  {
    if (data[i, j] is null)
    {
      isNullExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isNullExists)
  {
    int outputRows = filteredRowsCount;
    filteredRowsCount++;
    object[,] extendOutput = new object[filteredRowsCount, columns];
    for (int j = 0; j < outputRows; j++)
    {
      for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++)
      {
        extendOutput[j, k] = output[j, k];
      }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
      extendOutput[filteredRowsCount - 1, j] = data[i, j];
    }
    output = extendOutput;
  }
}

//далее работаем с output
```

Comment: первый элемент data начинается с [1, 1]. Чтобы не падало нужно в циклах с 1 начинать?

Comment: То есть... мы пропускаем первую строку `for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) { ... }`, а затем первый столбец пропускаем только на один раз `for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) { if (i == 1 && j == 0) continue; ... }`. Не совсем понимаю для чего это нужно , но может всё таки [1, 0]?